# appending data dynamically in as few loops as possible

Tags: c, for-loop, realloc, dynamic-allocation

I have a matrix `A=(n,m)` and I need to scan its columns one by one and if the sum of the elements of a column is greater than a threshold, put the column into a new matrix `B=(n,?)`.

```
A=[1 2 3
   3 1 1
   4 2 8]

threshold=6
```

And as result:

```
B=[1 3
   3 1
   4 8]
```

Obviously, i do not know how many columns in `B`, therefore in a first loop, I check the sum of elements in a column, then if the value is greater than the threshold I repeat the loop for appending the column in `B` by a `realloc`.

```
okcol=0;
double *B = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
for (col=0;col<m;col++){
  sum=0;
  for (row=0;row<n;row++){
    sum+=A[row+col*n];
    if(sum>threshold){
      B = realloc(B, (okcol+1)*n*sizeof(double));
      for (row2=0;row2<n;row2++){
        B [okcol*n+row2] = A[row2+col*n];
      }
      okcol++;
    }  
  }
}
```

Is there a method for automatically append the elements in `B` and "delete" them if the sum is less than threshold? In other words I would like to avoid the last loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing all this work yourself and are not leveraging an existing library?

Comment: Example? My code have to be wrapped in a mex file (matlab).

Comment: I have none (no experience with MATLAB). That's probably a detail you'd like to add to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linked list, so every time you just add an element (in this case the index of every column that meets the threshold) and at the end of the cycles you know how much memory you have to allocate to put in the columns into a simple 2 dimensional array.

You would at least a lot of reallocations in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
double *B = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
int c,r,okcol=0;
for(c=0;c<m;++c){
    for(sum=0, r=0;r<n;++r){
        sum+=(B[r+okcol*m]=A[r+c*m]);
    }
    if(sum > threshold)
        ++okcol;
}
B=(double*)realloc(B, okcol*m*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Please don't post just code as an answer.  Code is great, but your answer will be more helpful if you describe why you suggest this code over other solutions, how you arrived at it, and how it works.

Comment: Yes, to you and I it's obvious, but it's certainly easier for a learner to read text. "First, allocate enough memory for the entire matrix. Create a variable to track the number of acceptable columns.  Then, iterate through the columns in the old matrix.  As you summate each column, copy every value to the current column.  If the column's sum is insufficient, don't update the current column; let the next column overwrite the old one. This avoids the two-step approach and leads to faster code.  Finally, reallocate to fit only the acceptable columns."

Comment: The line `sum+=(B[r+okcol*m]=A[r+c*m]);` is simultaneously  one of the most important lines in the solution and the most difficult for someone new to C to read. Honestly, I'd refactor it into multiple lines if this would ever need to be debugged.  Also, your code isn't commented at all: using single-letter variables means your code isn't self-commenting, so this would be hard to maintain.  Furthermore, the intent of the code is only one part of the solution: you're not addressing the 'why'. [Code-only answers like this aren't welcome on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95470).

Comment: I don't think need comment for this level code.
May be changed if necessary to change the variable name and refactoring.

Comment: O.K., thank you BLUEPIXY and Kevin. 1st line `double *B = (double*)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));` does not solve my problem with memory, because `m` is huge... Therefore, my "solution" is: 
    
    `double *B = (double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
     int c,r,okcol=0;
     for(c=0;c<m;++c){
       for(sum=0, r=0;r<n;++r){
        sum+=(B[r+okcol*n]=A[r+c*n]);
    }
    if(sum > threshold){
    B=(double*)realloc(outdata, n*(okcol+2)*sizeof(double));
    ++okcol;
}`

Comment: In this way I allocate one more column for the next iteration. At the end of the loop I delete the last column by allocating the correct dimensions with something like  `mxArray *output = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, okcol, mxREAL);`

It seems to work. Are there any mistake in my code?

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY In your code `sum+=(B[r+okcol*m]=A[r+c*m]);
` should be replaced with `sum+=(B[r+okcol*n]=A[r+c*n]);
`

Comment: "because m is huge" ：I think B is by setting the threshold becomes a copy of A. I think it is good even if realloc Later, when you need of course.

Comment: "should be replaced" : you get and use it properly since it may have been confused with the m and n look at the code for you. Code is  only an example for an idea.